# External interrupt does not trigger when in Supervisor mode

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, riscv

I am writing a toy kernel to learn about operating systems. I am targeting a RISC-V machine (`virt` in `qemu`). I try to delegate interrupts to Supervisor mode, but I don't know why it does not work.

From what I read in the privileged architecture manual, I need to enable exceptions for supervisor in the `mie` CSR, and set bits from the exceptions I want to delegate in the `mideleg` and `medeleg` CSRs. But doing so does not raise any exception when having an external interrupt pending.

Software interrupts work, they are triggered and taken in S-mode, but External interrupts are not even triggering (not even in M-mode).

To understand what happens, I tried using `gdb` and watch for the `mip` register to change.
I trigger the interrupt with the UART0 port of the machine (by pressing a key on my keyboard) and here is what happen.

Pressing a key sets a bit in `mip` which pauses the execution. And here is the state of the relevant CSR:

```
(gdb) p /x $sip
$3 = 0x200
(gdb) p /x $sie
$4 = 0x222
(gdb) p /x $mstatus
$5 = 0xaa
(gdb) p /x $mideleg
$6 = 0x666
(gdb) p /x $medeleg
$7 = 0xb0bfff
(gdb) p /x $scause
$8 = 0x0
(gdb) p /x $stval
$9 = 0x0
```

So the SEIP (supervisor external interrupt pending)  bit is set, but nothing triggers. If I then continue execution I eventually trigger a Page Fault or an Illegal Instruction as these are software interrupts and are taken.

If I try to run a `wfi` instruction in supervisor mode, the same thing happens, and thuss the machine will be stuck at the `wfi` instruction.

Am I doing something wrong or is it `virt` ?
If this question lacks details, please tell me, I will modify it.

Edit: it seems like the board on which the virt machine is based has for Hart 0 a SiFive E51 processor which does not support supervisor mode at all and of course I was using this hart for my bootloader.

But still, why does the simulator allow supervisor mode on this hart even though the documentation explicitely tells it implements only M and U modes ? And why are the synchronous exceptions still delegated into S-mode ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Precisions about the `virt` RISC-V machine

Changing from Hart 0 to Hart 1 as my main core did not change the problem.

By printing the `misa` and `mimp` CSRs, I can now tell that all cores of the `virt` machine have the same `misa` and implement Supervisor mode. So the machine is not based on the FU53 platform architecture, it just uses the same kind of global interruption system with a PLIC.

But the PLIC memory map is not the same as the FU53 which has no S-mode global interrupt memory mapped registers for Hart 0. Because of that, the addresses I used to enable S-mode global interruption were not the good ones.

In this file: [qemu/virt.h at master · qemu/qemu](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/include/hw/riscv/virt.h#L73) you can find constants to use to compute the right PLIC addresses to use when setting it up.

I still don't fully understand why the pending bit in `mip` was set, but now it works.

### tl;dr

So here is the state which made it work when going into S-mode. The PLIC addresses were the culprit.

```
mstatus: MPIE = 1, SIE = 1, MPP = 01
mie    : MEIE = MTIE = MSIE = SEIE = STIE = SSIE = 1 (mie=0xaaa)
mideleg: 0x222
medeleg: 0xb0bfff (which is set when writing 0xffffffff to it)

PLIC:
  - *0x0C00_2080 (Hart 0 S-mode enable) = 0x400 (enable UART0)
  - *0x0C00_0028 (Interrupt number 10 priority) = 1
  - *0x0C20_1000 (Hart 0 S-mode threshold) = 0
```